# How to update the table with my inner join

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, inner-join

I want to update the value of column `PPVGLAccountID = 5`. Currently it shows 81.
But the problem is there are columns which doesn't below on the same table.
How can I use the query UPDATE and SET?

Thank you

[image: Please see the link]

My code is:

```
UPDATE dbo.POInvoicingDetails
SET PPVGLAccountID = '5'
FROM dbo.POInvoicingDetails
INNER JOIN dbo.POInvoicing PPVGLAccountID ON dbo.POInvoicingDetails.POInvoicingID
WHERE dbo.POInvoicing.InvoiceNo = '421009'
```

but I get an error where an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN your query there isn't correct syntax in `INNER JOIN` so have to slightly change it to the correct one as below and I hope you are using the correct conditions

```
UPDATE dbo.POInvoicingDetails
SET PPVGLAccountID ='5'
FROM dbo.POInvoicingDetails
--Condition were missing in the below line compare below line you will get the point
INNER JOIN dbo.POInvoicing ON dbo.POInvoicing.POInvoicingID = dbo.POInvoicingDetails.POInvoicingID
WHERE dbo.POInvoicing.InvoiceNo = '421009' 

'421009'--Should not in the quote if it's not `STRING or CHARACTER` type
```

**Note**: you can use table `alias` to make it easy to write and shorten the code

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
UPDATE id
SET PPVGLAccountID = '5'
FROM dbo.POInvoicingDetails id INNER JOIN
     dbo.POInvoicing i
     ON id.POInvoicingID = i.POInvoicingID
WHERE i.InvoiceNo = '421009';
```

Your `ON` clause is missing the `JOIN` condition.

Comment: hi, tried to execute it but there's an error saying "The multipart identifier "dbo.PoInvoicingID" could not be bound :( what does it mean?

Comment: @Trish try to remove that `dbo` word after ON clause and then check

Comment: @Parfait . . . Not according to the really hard to read image that has the join conditions in it.